# Draw on a CGContext from a CGImage

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, image, quartz-graphics

I would like to draw on a `CGContext` by using tiles from `CGImage` that I would like to draw in a specified order.

According to documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) it seems that the only method to draw an image in a graphic context is

```
void CGContextDrawImage (
   CGContextRef c,
   CGRect rect,
   CGImageRef image
);
```

But this doesn't take in account the case in which I want to draw just a `CGRect` of the source image. Do I have to do some tricks to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you are asking to crop an image at a particular `CGRect`, if so then you need to take a look at this method.

```
CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(CGImage image, CGRect rect)
```

This will return you a `CGImageRef` and according to your need I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that the result retains the original image and while it's faster than drawing the image to a context, it may consume more memory.

Answer (score 3):

This is listing 11-1 from Apple's *[Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBBGCII)*:

```
myImageArea = CGRectMake (rooster_head_x_origin, rooster_head_y_origin,
                            myWidth, myHeight);
mySubimage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect (myRoosterImage, myImageArea);
myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, myWidth*2, myHeight*2);
CGContextDrawImage(context, myRect, mySubimage);
```

Note that `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` returns a reference that you are responsible for releasing, so you'll need to do this when you're done with `mySubimage`:

```
CGImageRelease(mySubimage);
```